# which is the best way to structure the data on couchdb?

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework, nosql, couchdb

design two different structures for my couch database, I want to know which one suits me best.

**document by course:**

```
    {                   
  "_id": "e11b862c9939f9d0de39f3aa28036c96",
  "_rev": "4-e1245399d2f074ef5710d6bcbb0aa7f7",
  "nombre": "JavaScript",
  "descripcion": "curso basico de javascript",
  "horas": 50,
  "costo": 500000,
  "modalidades": [
    {
      "nombre": "online",
      "descripcion": "cursos en linea",
      "descuentos": [
        {
          "descuento": 0.2,
          "fecha caducidad": "2017-11-20"
        },
        {
          "descuento": 0.1,
          "fecha caducidad": "2017 - 12 - 30 "
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "privada",
      "descripcion": "cursos privados",
      "descuentos": [
        {
          "descuento": 0.2,
          "fecha caducidad": "2017-11-20"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I make a unique document where I keep the courses, the costs of the courses, and the discounts of each course depending on the modality, I want to know which of the two forms is more useful to administer

```
{
  "_id": "e11b862c9939f9d0de39f3aa28034b9e",
  "_rev": "3-87278a7404c9f458be9beec1808aafb7",
  "cursos": [
    {
      "nombre": "Javascript",
      "descripcion": "curso basico de javascript",
      "horas": 50,
      "costo": 500000,
      "modalidad": [
        {
          "nombre": "online",
          "descripcion": "cursos en linea",
          "descuentos": [
            {
              "descuento": 0.2,
              "fecha caducidad": "2017-12-20"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nombre": "privada",
          "descripcion": "cursos privados",
          "descuentos": [
            {
              "descuento": 0.15,
              "fecha caducidad": "2017-12-20"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "nombre": "HTML5",
      "descripcion": "curso basico de HTML5",
      "horas": 60,
      "costo": 400000,
      "modalidad": [
        {
          "nombre": "online",
          "descripcion": "cursos en linea",
          "descuentos": [
            {
              "descuento": 0.3,
              "fecha caducidad": "2017-12-20"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "nombre": "privada",
          "descripcion": "cursos privados",
          "descuentos": [
            {
              "descuento": 0.2,
              "fecha caducidad": "2017-12-20"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is a broad question and should be asked in a different forum, unless you ask a specific question about these two codes

Comment: thanks for the answer ibo, the concrete question is, which of the structures is the most appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

As you've not provided any clues on how you intend to actually *use* the data, it's hard to offer more than generic advice. However...

It's typically easier to get good performance out of CouchDB/Cloudant following the *first* approach -- a separate, small document for each course, rather than one large document holding data about all courses. It depends on the usage patterns your application will exhibit. I would guess that the course data will change only infrequently (good for performance, and low likelihood of conflicts), and that the application will mainly need access to course data on a per-course basis.

I would go for the first approach, and construct a view to provide access to all courses by name. That way you would never need to load all course data to simply expose data about your JavaScript course, for example.